# Node.js cannot find module & etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian

So i have a node.js script that came with some modules and i am struggling to run it (Debian 7). I have searched through and tried different "solutions" but none of them work, help would be nice.

this is my console output:

```
`root@185:/home/bot# node sell.js
module.js:457
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './parser/token_analyzer'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. <anonymous>     (/home/bot/node_modules/steam/resources/steam_language_parser/index.js:2:22)
 at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

I tried this on my windows and it worked but it just doesnt work on my debian sever for some reason

Parser/token_analyzer directory:

```
bot\node_modules\steam\resources\steam_language_parser\parser\token_analyzer.js
```

FILE THAT REQUESTED the parser/token_analyzer:

```
bot\node_modules\steam\resources\steam_language_parser\index.js
```

CODE:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var token_analyzer = require('./parser/token_analyzer');

var codeGen = require('./generator/node_gen');
var languagePath = require('path').join(__dirname, '../steam_language');

var cwd = process.cwd();
process.chdir(languagePath);

var tokenList = require('./parser/language_parser').tokenizeString(fs.readFileSync('steammsg.steamd', { encoding: 'ascii' }));

var root = token_analyzer.analyze(tokenList);

process.chdir(cwd);

var rootEnumNode = new token_analyzer.Node();
var rootMessageNode = new token_analyzer.Node();

rootEnumNode.childNodes = root.childNodes.filter( function(n) { return n instanceof token_analyzer.EnumNode; });
rootMessageNode.childNodes = root.childNodes.filter( function(n) { return n instanceof token_analyzer.ClassNode; });

require('./code_generator').emitCode(rootEnumNode, codeGen);
require('./code_generator').emitCode(rootMessageNode, codeGen);
```

Comment: Can you show your file where you required `'./parser/token_analyzer'`? and where this file exist?

Comment: And of course, do you have a file called `token_analyzer.js` in a `parser` directory that's a peer of `sell.js`?

Comment: parser directory is :

Comment: bot\node_modules\steam\resources\steam_language_parser\parser

Comment: bot being the starting directory with sell.js

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand

Your sell.js is above node modules directory. It should be along with node_modules or even deeper. You say your directory structure be like

|
|---- bot/node_modules/steam/resources/steam_language_parser/parse‌​r/token_analyzer.js
|---- sell.js

This won't work at all.
But the below will work

|
|---- bot/node_modules/steam/resources/steam_language_parser/parse‌​r/token_analyzer.js
|---- bot/sell.js

FYI I converted all \ to /, why the hell are you even denoting in \'s if you are using linux?